# strange html attribute that i can not understand

Tags: javascript, html

I have been learning web programming (part time) for a about a year right now. Please could any one tell me what is the meaning of:

```
<html class="ws" data-19ax5a9jf="dingo">
```

and any more information about it and why used? I found this in an html element:. I have surfed the net, but found no clue. Many Thanks

Comment: Please post the actual HTML in question. It sounds like a data attribute, but the `:` is strange.

Comment: Try to be more specific here. Show us the html code because this could be also manipulated html with javascript.

Comment: Sorry the colon doesn't exist, is just a way of writing, here is it:
    <html class="ws" data-19ax5a9jf="dingo">

Comment: HTML5 has the ability to store data for tags in custom attributes of the form `data-*`. See [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) for additional information.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 2):

From the specification: "A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no characters in the range U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z)."

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes